# Apache conditional rewrite rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble modying a URL on the fly.

I want to find and replace a string in the middle of a url like so:

```
localhost/existing/template-one/index.html
```

Needs to be changed to

```
localost/template-one/index.html
```

The only caveat is that /template-one/ could also be /template-two/ or /template-three etc etc.

So basically, where ever we see /template-something following /existing/ we want to get rid of /existing

So far I have this:

```
^/existing/?(.*) /$1
```

but this happens in ALL cases rather than being conditional!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the following rule :

```
RewriteRule ^existing/template-(.*) template-$1
```

The parenthesis will match anything after `existing/template-` and rewrite it to `template-<anything>`